# Как из массива вытащить 3 наиболее часто повторяющихся элемента?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, словари

Господа помогите:
Как мне из массива вытащить 3 наиболее часто повторяющихся элемента и сколько раз он повторился? 
Не соображу как сделать именно 3 наибольших. Ну или 5 - не важно - главное не все повторяющиеся (это можно через Counter), а конкретное количество самых частых.

Предположим есть массив слов:

```
['я', 'он', 'они', 'она', 'мы', 'вы', 'ты', 'я', 'он', 'она', 'ты', 'я', 'вы']
```

В результате мне нужно получить что то вроде:

```
{'я': 3, 'он': 2, 'она': 2}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [Counter(...).most_common(n)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [74]: from collections import Counter

In [75]: c = Counter(['я', 'он', 'они', 'она', 'мы', 'вы', 'ты', 'я', 'он', 'она', 'ты', 'я', 'вы'])

In [76]: c.most_common(3)
Out[76]: [('я', 3), ('он', 2), ('она', 2)]
```

или в виде словаря:

```
In [77]: dict(c.most_common(3))
Out[77]: {'я': 3, 'он': 2, 'она': 2}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не знал об этом методе.

Answer (score 1):

Если есть желание использовать только `core`-методы, то можно сделать так:

```
lst = ['я', 'он', 'они', 'она', 'мы', 'вы', 'ты', 'я', 'он', 'она', 'ты', 'я', 'вы']
d = dict.fromkeys(lst,0)
for x in lst:
    d[x]+=1
res = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:3]
```

Тогда `res` будет:

```
[('я', 3), ('он', 2), ('она', 2)]
```

Ну и соответственно, `dict(res)` :

```
{'я': 3, 'он': 2, 'она': 2}
```

Comment: Зачем минусовать работающие решения??